# favicon.ico not read in app engine for chrome

Tags: python, google-app-engine, favicon

I am developing a web app in app engine python, I cant find GET /favicon.ico in console when I execute it in chrome or IE. Whereas there is no issue with firefox or safari, my favicon.ico is displayed in it.

here is my handlers in app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico

- url: /sitemap.xml    
  static_files: sitemap.xml
  upload: sitemap.xml

- url: /robots.txt    
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

There is no 404 error for favicon, /facivon.ico not getting executed in chrome , IE.

Comment: Since it works with FF/Safari, your app.yaml is set up properly (although the indentation is wrong in the post).  This is probably browser specific behavior.  You may need to add <link rel="shortcut icon"> tag into your html.

Comment: I tried using <link rel="shortcut icon"> and <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">, still no luck

Comment: I am able to fix this by simply moving my /favicon.ico to /static/favicon.ico ! Its works cool. I dont know why that works now . U got any idea ? thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
- url: /favicon\.ico
  mime_type: image/vnd.microsoft.icon
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico
```